# WiFi Positioning System (WPS) setup

Tags: development, .net, geoprocessing, geocoding, mobile

I need to develop a shopping mall GIS. I have no idea to develop it. The shopping mall GIS should function like GPS (guides user to desire shops). Do I need to set up some GIS device at each corner of shopping mall, in order to keep track location of user? What are those devices?

Does anyone involve in GIS development before? I need your help.

Through  an extensive research, WiFi Positioning System (WPS) is the only feasible solution.

One of the features of my system: 
- Example, you connect to a shopping mall WiFi using your mobile phone (iPhone, Windows Phone 7, Android Phone, etc). It will redirect to the main page. You can find desired location by clicking "search" button. It will guide you the way to the specific shop (like google map). A red dot in the map represents your current location. The red dot will move if you are moving. WIFI Positioning System is the way to achieve this. How to setup WIFI Positioning System? What kind of device I need? Does anyone have experience and knowledge in this kind of development? I am totally new in this kind of development. Please share your opinion and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Bing Map do this - http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2010/12/07/bing-s-new-mall-maps-get-in-get-out-and-the-avoid-the-crowds.aspx

Using a mobile device will triangulate to locate the users position.
(Just don't fall in any fountains whilst your looking at your phone!)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking#Network-based

Example Mall Map:
http://www.bing.com/maps/?ss=ypid.YN633x14747926&form=vemaps&vm=HCL-RooseveltFieldMall&i=1

note: not all mobile/cell devices have wifi.